# iOS Automation Shortcuts - Daylight Savings Time

Tags: ios, shortcuts-app, timezone

I have an Automation Shortcut on my iPhone that uses the Time of Day trigger and is set to trigger at 1:30 each morning.  This Sunday is a Daylight Savings Time change (I am in the US/New York timezone) and 1:30 AM will occur twice.  Will my Automation Shortcut trigger twice?

Is there a way to specify a Time of Day trigger in UTC or another non-ambiguous time system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We learn by trying…

The Time of Day trigger only triggered once… at the first 1:30 AM.
I stayed up to watch it and after it triggered, the next occurrence advanced to Monday morning, causing it to not be triggered an hour later.